Calculating the trapezoid angle needed to fill the space to produce an n-gon cone
The situation is a bit convoluted. But essentially I am trying to create a bowl using a table saw. This table saw can do angled cuts (we call them mitered cuts) as well as tilt the table saw.
I am following this guide here which gives a table of the saw tilt and miter angle you would allegedly need to fit this shape.

There is only one problem. I think the math for saw tilt angle is a bit off. I realized this when trying to recreate this in cad.
Now he uploaded his own CAD file and I opened it. I am not really super familiar with that software but I am not convinced he tested every case like I can in mine.
For example with 3 sides and a 30 degree tilt he finds a miter angle of 40.89 and a saw blade tilt of 48.59 but I find that leaves a small gap and that the saw blade tilt needs to be more like 56.3 degrees.
I think the calculation for that which he defines as
a=polygonSideAngle (in this case 30 degrees)
splayx = tilt from 90 degrees
splayyc = atan(tan(splayx)/cos(a))
atan(tan(a)*cos(splayyc)

But doesnt really go into the derivation. I am fairly handy with geometry but I cant seem to sort it out myself due to the 3D nature of everything.
Because sides are tilted up that top face that must connect are on two different planes.
Here's how I am essentially seeing the problem. And it is possible I am modeling it wrong or my cad file is wrong. I dont know how to solve it because while I can derive in 2D that the angle between these sides should be (it should be the polygon angle) as soon as the top are tilted... I am not really sure what to do.
Its like I need to figure out the angle needed where when projected at the tilt angle will result in them being together.
I even brute force used my CAD model to estimate the values for side count of 3 to try and give myself an idea of what I might need to brute force this with. The grey line shows promise that this can be solved with the right trigonometry.
I am progressively realizing that linear algebra with vectors and projecting vectors onto a plane is probably a possible solution here. I can actually get my CAD software to calculate this angle this way but cannot drive geometry with that calculation. Even though a linear algebra solution would be great to see an algebraic definition that does not require any matrix/vector multiplications would be much more feasible to put into my CAD software.




